# How to layout UICollectionView with tabbar on SupplementaryView, and switching different content?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, autolayout, uicollectionview

I want to implement the UICollectionView effect with tabbar and possible to switch different content like a lot of social app does.

[image]

You can click `Home` to display timeline and click `Album` to display photos on content area. The top of content like avatar and username are no change, and the content offset will keep the same when you switch is completed.

I try it with a UICollectionView containing SupplementaryView for displaying avatar and handling tabbar click event. Assign different delegate, dataSource and layout object while switching different content. But I got a lot of problem and crash.

What's the correct way to implement this kind of layout and how to handle switching event?

Comment: Have you watched the [“Advanced User Interfaces with Collection Views” video from WWDC 2014](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-232/), and looked at the [associated “AdvancedCollectionView” sample code](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2015/?q=advancedcollectionview)? You should find it very helpful.

Comment: Why would you use a tab bar? I would have used a simple segmented control view or maybe use something like https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the top part of your view does not change and remains as the logo with an avatar. If this is the case I would not worry about supplementary views. Supplementary views are more for section headers/separators in a similar way to the use of section headers for UITableViews. Instead have a container view at the bottom which would hold the collectionView with UISegmentedControl above which would trigger the changes in the container view. If the container is to display the same data with different layouts (ie. photos scrolling vertically to horizontally) then the segmented control could trigger a change to the collectionViewFlowLayout but if the data changes (ie Timeline to Album) then I would suggest switching to different child view controllers in the container view triggered from the segmented control actions. You would probably want to save the current scroll offset in the container view controllers so that it can be restored when switching back. Also having separate child view controller classes will help prevent the container view controller from getting too large and keep each child collection  view controller simple and focused.

Comment: And how about handling scroll touch on the top of the area? When you touch on the header area and scroll down, the whole of the collectionView should also scroll down together. scrolling up also.

Answer (score 1):

Just decompose your logic, there is no necessity to keep everything in one `UICollectionView` and switch data sources and delegates.

Answer (score 0):

With CollectionView 
https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout

Without CollectionView (test project created for demo purpose) 
https://github.com/rishi420/issue-12-interactive-animations-uidynamics

For segment control 
https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNSegmentedControl

With collectionView, first section in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is the profile picture area. Second section in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is another view which contains a segment control with all 3 (Home, Album, Profile) scrollable views.

You can also create a pull-able view which stays fixed at the bottom part of the screen or takes more space as user scroll up.